# Where is _ctypes._SimpleCData.__mul__() method implemented?

Tags: python, ctypes

For example:

```
>>> ctypes.c_char * 2
<type '_ctypes.SimpleType'>
```

The type `c_char_Array_2` is created on the fly by the `__mul__()` method in `_ctypes._SimpleCData`，I want to know how it did that, but I can't find any source code about the `__mul__()` method, can somebody help?

Comment: I think you messed up the code sample. It should be `<class 'some-module.c_char_Array_2'>` instead of `<type '_ctypes.SimpleType'>`

Comment: @Bakuriu Sorry, my mistake when copy-paste, It's <class '__main__.c_char_Array_2'>

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a look at the C source implementation of `ctypes`, you can find it [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/_ctypes). `ctypes` is implemented in C, so you won't find the implementation of `__mul__` in any `.py` file.

Somthing like this in python can be done using [metaclassing](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/MetaClasses).
simple example:

```
class Spam(type):
    def spam(cls): print("spam:", cls.__name__)
    def __mul__(self, other):
        ' create a new class on the fly and return it '
        class Eggs(metaclass=Spam):
            def eggs(self): print("eggs" * other)
        return Eggs

class Ham(metaclass=Spam):
    def ham(self): print('ham')

print(Ham)                 # <class '__main__.Eggs'>
Ham.spam()                 # spam: Ham
Ham().ham()                # ham
# create new class:
TwoEggs = Ham * 2
print(TwoEggs)             # <class '__main__.Eggs'>
TwoEggs.spam()             # spam: Eggs
TwoEggs().eggs()           # eggseggs
```

(pyhton3 syntax, python2 uses `__metaclass__` attribute instead of `metaclass` argument.)

Comment: The Op did say that he can't find the implementation of `__mul__` in the source code, which implies he already read the source code but couldn't understand where `__mul__` is defined.

Comment: @Bakuriu I found the answer in the source code: Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c:CDataType_repeat(), Objects/typeobject.c: SQSLOT("__mul__", sq_repeat, NULL, wrap_indexargfunc, "x.__mul__(n) <==> x*n")

Comment: __mul__() does not always implement in PyNumberMethods.nb_multiply

Comment: @zJay then you should post your answer to your own question and accept it.